# iOS push notification images in content

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications

How can we add icon images in ios push notification content[image: like this one]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are Unicode emoji characters, not pictures:

You may illustrate your content with any Unicode emojis that are supported on iPhone, find more at https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html.